# scroll view isn't scrolling when compiled

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have the following app that I've implemented a scroll view (image outlines hierarchy  on storyboard:e

[image: Hierarchy of storyboard]

I have turned off Auto Layout, as severe posts here seem to indicate this creates a problem.

here is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/ALAsset.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/ALAssetRepresentation.h>
#import <ImageIO/CGImageSource.h>
#import <ImageIO/CGImageProperties.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>



@interface DobInAHoonViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *vehiclePickerView;
    UIImagePickerController *picker1;
    UIImagePickerController *picker2;
    UIImage *image;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CGFloat animatedDistance;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *BackgroundImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *Latitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *longditute;
@property  (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *toRecipients;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *groups;


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *vehilceMake;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *vehilceColour;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *regoNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *additionalInfo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *vehicleType;


- (IBAction)takePhoto;
-(IBAction)chooseExisting;
-(IBAction)actionEmailComposer;
-(IBAction)textFileReturn:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)DismissKeyboard:(id)sender;
@end
```

and my .m file:

```
#import "DobInAHoonViewController.h"

@interface DobInAHoonViewController ()



@end

@implementation DobInAHoonViewController
@synthesize BackgroundImage;
@synthesize vehilceColour;
@synthesize vehilceMake;
@synthesize regoNumber;
@synthesize Latitude;
@synthesize location;
@synthesize longditute;
@synthesize additionalInfo;
@synthesize toRecipients;
@synthesize assetsLibrary;
@synthesize groups;
@synthesize vehicleType;
@synthesize scrollView;



static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLLFRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 140;




-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [vehilceMake resignFirstResponder];
    [vehilceMake resignFirstResponder];
    [vehilceColour resignFirstResponder];
    [location resignFirstResponder];
    [additionalInfo resignFirstResponder];
    [regoNumber resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}






- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, 1000))];


    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    toRecipients = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"scott.boon@shellharbour.nsw.gov.au", nil];

    BackgroundImage.alpha = 0.3;
    static int emergAlertCounter;
    if (emergAlertCounter <1) {


    UIAlertView *emergencyAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"NOTE" message:@"Do not endanger your life to dob in a hoon. If your life is threatened, or you are reporting an emergency situation, exit this app and dial '000' IMMEDIATLY!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [emergencyAlert show];
        emergAlertCounter = emergAlertCounter+1;
    }
}
```

for some reason, when i run the app, the scroll view is not scrolling. I have set the property to scroll in the interface builder.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make sure your scroll view is smaller than 320 x 1000 and that the embedded view is larger than 320 x 1000